# How to click upload button in selenium rc using Google chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-rc

I have written the code for upload image using autoit tool. Its working fine firefox browser. i tried to execute same thing in Google chrome by changing the browser to *googlechorme.
But i am unable to open browsing dialogue box in chrome. I used click command as i have used same for Firefox. Can any body help me on this???

Comment: Can you please past your auto it code ?

Answer (score 0):

try selenium.keyPressNative("10");